# HTML5: Change the language on an object loaded on a div as external html file

Tags: html, selector, external, lang

HTML5: Change the language on an object loaded on a div as external html file

I have a language selector. I have succeeded to change language on the start page. However, I could not find the way to work universally on all objects that are loaded in the main div, as external html files.

I dont want to install the language selector, and its script in every html file. I want to be the language selector, and the language script in the main html only e.g. index.html.

How can I do that ?

The problem:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">    
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">    

    <!-- stylesheet css -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <!-- google web font css -->
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:400,300,600,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

</head>


<body>    
        <a id=idStatistics     href ="#Statistics"      onclick="load_services()"> <span lang="en">Statistics      </span>     <span lang="gr">Στατιστική      </span>   </a>

            <select id="lang-switch">
              <option value="en">English</option>
              <option value="gr">Greek</option>
            </select>

        <script>
        //stackoverflow: 13591983   // This script MUST BE under the "ID" that is calling // Do not transfer it to a differ DIV than the caller "ID"
            document.getElementById("idStatistics").addEventListener("click", function(){
            document.getElementById("mainbody").innerHTML = '<object data="Statistics.html" class="Statistics_page"; ></object>'; });
        </script>   

<div id="mainbody" class="main_body">

<p lang="en">
Statistics is a science based on probabilities
Statistics is a science based on probabilities
    </p>

<p lang="gr">
Στατιστιστική 
Στατιστική
 </p>


</div>


<script>
    // Taken by 49637061 on stackoverflow
$('[lang="es"]').hide();
$('[lang="gr"]').hide();

$('#lang-switch').change(function () {
  var lang = $(this).val();
  switch (lang) {
    case 'en': 
      $('[lang]').hide();
      $('[lang="en"]').show();
      break;
    case 'gr':
      $('[lang]').hide();
      $('[lang="gr"]').show();
      break;
    default:
      $('[lang]').hide();
      $('[lang="en"]').show();

if ($.cookie('lang') === 'en') {
   $.cookie('lang', 'gr', { expires: 7 });
     } else {
       $.cookie('lang', 'en', { expires: 7 });
     }       
  }
});
</script>

</body>

</html>
```

and the external html file...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="keywords" content="">
    <meta name="description" content="">

    <!-- stylesheet css -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <!-- google web font css -->
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:400,300,600,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>


</head>

<body>


<span lang="en">
    <div id="Statistics_page" class="Statistics_htmlfile_page">

Statistics is a science based on probabilities
  Statistics is a science based on probabilities
Statistics is a science based on probabilitiesStatistics is a science 
</div>
</span>


<span lang="gr">
<div id="Statistics_page2" class="Statistics_htmlfile_page">

Στατιστιστική 
Στατιστική

</div>
</span>

</body>
```

I would probably be interested of something like this...

```
    "       <script>
    document.getElementById("idR_Code_PSPP").addEventListener("click", function(){

   if lang=en do that:   document.getElementById("mainbody").innerHTML = '<object data="R_Code_PSPP.html" class="R_Code_PSPP_page"; >        
   if lang=gr, do that: document.getElementById("mainbody").innerHTML = '<object data="Statistics.html" class="Statistics_page"; ></object>'; });
    </object>';});
            </script>"
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I found that the code was not working outside a server environment - at least not with my settings e.g. `file:// .....`

In linux, I must set a local server e.g. `sudo python -m SimpleHTTPServer`
 in order to run webpage's Jquery code successfully.

Then, I must type `http://0.0.0.0:8000/index.html` in a web browser in order to run the website in a proper manner.

Note, that you may need to **clear Browser's cache** in order to see the updated version of your website between edits.

The div part on the index.html was that --note the "id" declaration:

```
<a href="index.html"   class="topnav_estatistics">ESTATISTICS </a>
    <a id=idStatistics     href ="#Statistics"      > <span lang="en">Statistics        </span>     <span lang="gr">Στατιστική      </span>   </a>
    <a id=info_page        href ="#info_page"       > <span lang="en">info_page      </span>    <span lang="gr"> info_page  </span>   </a>
    <a id=articles         href ="#articles"        > <span lang="en">Stat Articles   </span>     <span lang="gr"> Άρθρα          </span>   </a>   
    <a id=Planets_Health   href ="#Planets_Health"  > <span lang="en">Planet's Health </span>     <span lang="gr"> Περιβάλλον     </span>   </a>    
    <a id=Services         href ="#Services"        > <span lang="en">Services        </span>     <span lang="gr"> Υπηρεσίες      </span>   </a>
```

The code for language selector was like that in index.html page, after head:

```
 <!--- The Language options  --->
            <select id="lang_switch" class="lang_switch">
               <option value="en">En </option>
               <option value="gr">Gr </option>
            </select>
```

The external html information was added to the following divs of index.html page in the body section:

```
<div id="left_link_index" class="left_link_index"> 

<div id="mainbody" class="main_body">
```

The "statistics.html" page in body part was like that:

```
 <body>
   <div id="Statistics_page"  class="Statistics_htmlfile_page">
   <div id="stat"  class="stat_main">

    <div id="st_en"  lang="en" class="stat_en">
    Statistics is a science based on probabilities
    </div>

    <div id="st_gr"  lang="gr" class="stat_gr">
    Στατιστιστική 
    Στατιστική
    Στατιστιστική
    </div>

    </div>

    <div id="left_links_en"  class="Statistics_links">
        <a href ="#Articles" >    <li>    <span lang="en"> Articles       </span>  </li>   </a>  

      </div>

    <div id="left_links_gr"  class="Statistics_links">
        <a href ="#Articles" >    <li>    <span lang="gr"> Αρθρογραφία    </span>  </li>   </a> 

    </div>

    </body>
```

a) The script cod to change ( switch ) the language between different language options as well b) the script code to insert parts of external html page into a number of divs --based on language selections, was that:

```
<script>
    // stackoverflow: 49637061  &  11134701 
 //Default settings 
$('[lang="en"]').show();
$('[lang="gr"]').hide();
          $(document).ready(function(){
           $("#info_page").click(function(){
             $("#mainbody").load("info_page.html #st_en"); 
             $("#left_link_index").load("info_page.html #left_links_en"); 
          });
           $("#stat_page").click(function(){
             $("#mainbody").load("stat_page.html #st_en"); 
             $("#left_link_index").load("stat_page.html #left_links_en"); 

          }); 
           $("#articles_page").click(function(){
             $("#mainbody").load("articles_page.html #st_en"); 
          }); 
           $("#Planets_Health").click(function(){
             $("#mainbody").load("Planets_Health.html #st_en"); 
          }); 
           $("#Services").click(function(){
             $("#mainbody").load("Services.html #st_en"); 
          }); 
          }); 

$('#lang_switch').change(function () {
  var lang = $(this).val();
  switch (lang) {
    case 'gr':
      $('[lang]').hide();
      $('[lang="gr"]').show();
          $(document).ready(function(){
           $("#info_page").click(function(){
             $("#mainbody").load("info_page.html #st_gr"); 
             $("#left_link_index").load("info_page.html #left_links_gr"); 
          });
           $("#stat_page").click(function(){
             $("#mainbody").load("stat_page.html #st_gr"); 
             $("#left_link_index").load("stat_page.html #left_links_gr"); 
          }); 
           $("#articles").click(function(){
             $("#mainbody").load("articles.html #st_gr"); 
          }); 
           $("#Planets_Health").click(function(){
             $("#mainbody").load("Planets_Health.html #st_gr"); 
          }); 
           $("#Services").click(function(){
             $("#mainbody").load("Services.html #st_gr"); 
          }); 
          }); 
      break;
      case 'en':
      $('[lang]').hide();
      $('[lang="gr"]').show();
          $(document).ready(function(){
           $("#info_page").click(function(){
             $("#mainbody").load("info_page.html #st_en"); 
             $("#left_link_index").load("info_page.html #left_links_en"); 

          });
           $("#stat_page").click(function(){
             $("#mainbody").load("Statistics.html #st_en"); 
             $("#left_link_index").load("stat_page.html #left_links_en"); 
          }); 
           $("#articles").click(function(){
             $("#mainbody").load("articles.html #st_en"); 
          }); 
           $("#Planets_Health").click(function(){
             $("#mainbody").load("Planets_Health.html #st_en"); 
          }); 
           $("#Services").click(function(){
             $("#mainbody").load("Services.html #st_en"); 
          }); 
          }); 
      break;
  };
});
</script>
```

Note that the formatting options of the loaded external html page into the index.html are available through: **".left_link_index{ }" and ".mainbody { }"** options, in general. Specifically, you can declare additional e.g. div id codes or class codes in order to format specific parts of the external inserted pieces of html into the index main page.